# What's the difference between DLGTableLayOut(2, 1, 0) and DLGLayout(DLGCreateTableLayout(2, 1, 0))

Tags: user-interface, dialog, dm-script

all:
In the DM manual, I saw there are two ways to define layout, DLGTableLayOut(2, 1, 0) and DLGLayout(DLGCreateTableLayout(2, 1, 0)). I tried them, and seems the same. Is there any difference?

Regards

Chen ZX

Comment: General info on DM-script dialogs: They are clumsy and you likely *will* experience some frustration with things not working exactly as you want. While one can generate some decent output with enough effort, my advice would be: Keep the UI simple and functional. Also: You likely will encounter commands or attributes that seemingly do *nothing*. This is because a lot of the script code evolved over decades with GMS UI changing a couple of times underneath and not all functionality being kept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All DLG commands only generated or modify a single TagGroup that describes the dialog.
If two commands produces the same TagGroup, they are, indeed, identical.
You can best check this using the command `TagGroupOpenBrowserWindow()` to visualize the tagGroup.

```c
TagGroup dlg,dlgItems
// The Command to generate a dialog just generates a structured TagGroup
// dlgItems just points to the "Items" subgroup of the same TagGroup
dlg = DLGCreateDialog("Test",dlgItems)

// Show the TagGroup at any step. Using "clone" to have a copy
// as the original will be further modified below.
dlg.TagGroupClone().TagGroupOpenBrowserWindow("Just created",0)

// Adding items just adds to the  "Items" TagGroup with correct structure and defaults
dlg.DLGAddElement( DLGCreateStringField("Text 1") )
dlg.DLGAddElement( DLGCreateStringField("Text 2", 12) )
TagGroup textItems
dlg.DLGAddElement( DLGCreateStringField("Label", textItems, "Text 3", 14) )
dlg.TagGroupClone().TagGroupOpenBrowserWindow("Added Fields",0)

// Some DLG command affect the overall structure, adding or overwriting tags
dlg.DLGTableLayout(2,2,1)
dlg.TagGroupClone().TagGroupOpenBrowserWindow("Added Table Layout",0)

dlg.DLGTableLayout(3,1,0)
dlg.TagGroupClone().TagGroupOpenBrowserWindow("Modified Table Layout",0)

// You can often do whatever you want - but it will not be "understood" by the code
// buidling the final dialog object later...
taggroup layoutTags = NewTagGroup()
layoutTags.TagGroupSetTagAsString("My own", "I do what I want!")
dlg.DLGLayout(layoutTags)
dlg.TagGroupClone().TagGroupOpenBrowserWindow("Setting customs tags (invalid)",0)
```